# Deploying a jersey grizzly service to tomcat with spring

Tags: spring, jax-rs, maven-3, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I am new to jersey and using it for the first time one of my RESTful services. I was able to build and run the "maven way" as given in the jersey download site. It uses the http container (grizzly),
Now, I want to deploy this as a war file on tomcat or generic 3.0 servlet containers.
I know that I need to have a war package + web.xml file.
My question is,

1. what do I put in this web.xml?
2. how do I add the tomcat plugin to maven build dependency? so that I can run this

   > mvn clean compile package tomcat7:run
3. If I need to add the spring framework later, how easy is that? How can I do that?

Comment: you have problem with grizzly or jersy ..can u add current web.xml

Comment: I used the maven command to create the project. mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2
 from the jersey site 
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html
This did not have a web.xml, hence my question